# Configuring localhost and virtalhost redirecting in dashboard with lampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, lampp

I'm attempting to configure a virtualhost to a subdirectory into /opt/lampp/htdocs. This is the httpd-vhost.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
ServerAdmin localhost
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs
ServerName localhost
<Directory  /opt/lampp/htdocs>      
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
# This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
ServerName www.localhostwmf.com
ServerAlias localhostwmf.com
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/wmf
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory  /opt/lampp/htdocs/wmf>

    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I uncommented this line in httpd.conf:

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And i added the following line in etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   www.localhostwmf.com
```

But it redirects me always in the dashboard page of xampp! Thank you in advance for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this morning the problem, i hope that this solution will be useful for another one:

I modified my httpd-vhosts.conf file as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
ServerAdmin localhost
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/wmf
ServerName localhost
<Directory  /opt/lampp/htdocs>      
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
# This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
ServerName www.localhostwmf.com
ServerAlias localhostwmf.com
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/wmf
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory  /opt/lampp/htdocs/wmf>

    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(i added wmf folder in localhost document root)